# How to slice a pandas.Series of type int by length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas.Series` that is an integer with 5 digits. The first 3 digits are days from an epoch, and the last 2 are half-hours. I want to slice the integer series, so that I have two `Series` with the first 3 digits and the last 2 digits respectively.

Here is one way to do it, that requires two type conversions:

```
import pandas as pd    
days_hours = pd.Series(npr.randint(low=1e4, high=99999, size=1000))
days = days_hours.astype('str').str.slice(start=0, stop=3).astype('int64')
hours = days_hours.astype('str').str.slice(start=3, stop=5).astype('int64')
```

This is very time-consuming given that on average my `Series` are 25e6 rows each (there are 6 such `Series`s). Is there a way that I can avoid the type conversions?

I tried an alternate solution which involved `apply`ing a `lambda` function to each element of the `Series` but that took longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be much quicker to do these operations arithmetically using integer division and the modulo operator:

```
days = days_hours // 100

hours = days_hours % 100
```

Comment: That answer was staring me in the face -- thank you. Considerable speedups.

Comment: Considerably simpler code, too, which is also important